# Pandas dataframe group by order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have the input dataframe:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory","Mallory", "Bob" ,"Bob", "Mallory", "Alice"] , 
    "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle"] } )
```

And I want to groupby Name, but not unique, so the output should be:

```
["Alice","Bob","Mallory","Bob","Mallory", "Alice"]
```

I couldn't find any efficient way to do it - is there a way without iterating all rows?

Comment: `df1.groupby(df1.Name.ne(df1.Name.shift()).cumsum()).Name.first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
df1.groupby((df1['Name'] != df1['Name'].shift()).cumsum()).first()
```

Yields:

```
         Name      City
Name                   
1       Alice   Seattle
2         Bob   Seattle
3     Mallory  Portland
4         Bob  Portland
5     Mallory   Seattle
6       Alice   Seattle
```

If you just want the `'Name'` column:

```
df1.groupby((df1['Name'] != df1['Name'].shift()).cumsum())['Name'].first().values
```

Yields:

```
['Alice' 'Bob' 'Mallory' 'Bob' 'Mallory' 'Alice']
```